# Putnam Exam Integral: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\big)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

I am trying to evaluate$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\big)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n.
$$
This is from an old Putnam mathematics competition. Either 1965 or 1987 I forget. Should we re-write the $\cos^2$ term first or how should we approach it?  Thanks

Comment: maybe write cosine in the $e^i$ form?

Comment: Another idea, you could use this relation: $$\cos^2\Big( \frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+\ldots + x_n)\Big) = \frac{1}{4}\Big( e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)} + e^{-\frac{i\pi}{n}(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)} \Big) + \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: It is a trick question, the expression is constant for all $n:\;\sum x_i\mapsto n-\sum x_i:$ gives $\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\cos^{2}\left[\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum x_i\right] \;\mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n=\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\sin^{2}\left[\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum x_i\right] \;\mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n$. Add.

Comment: @JulienGodawatta This is off the Putnam math exam, what do you mean it is a "trick"?  This is standard for the exam questions.

Comment: Integral's idea works perfectly. Also, if you want some sledgehammer method, just refer to the [Strong law of large number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law). It tells us that $\bar{x}_{n} = \frac{1}{n}(x_{1} + \cdots + x_{n}) \to \frac{1}{2}$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$, where $x_{k}$ are understood as i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$. So by the bounded convergence, the integral converges to $$ \Bbb{E}[\cos^{2}(\pi \bar{x}_{n} / 2) ] \to \Bbb{E}[\cos^{2}(\pi/4)] = \frac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: @Jeff Perhaps it was a bad choice of words - the question presents a limit when in fact we needn't think about limits at all, is what I meant.

Comment: @sos440 Sledgehammer? Maybe, but a really elegant (and deep) one, if you ask me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ldots\int_{0}^{1}
\cos^{2}\pars{{\pi \over 2n}\,\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n}}}
\,\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}\ldots\dd x_{n}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\bracks{%
1 + \color{#00f}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ldots\int_{0}^{1}
\cos\pars{{\pi \over n}\,\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n}}}
\,\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}\ldots\dd x_{n}}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ldots\int_{0}^{1}
> \cos\pars{{\pi \over n}\,\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n}}}
> \,\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}\ldots\dd x_{n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\Re\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ldots\int_{0}^{1}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic\pi x/n}\delta\pars{x - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k}}\,\dd x
> \,\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}\ldots\dd x_{n}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\Re\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ldots\int_{0}^{1}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic\pi x/n}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{\ic q\bracks{x - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k}}}
> \,{\dd q \over 2\pi}\,\dd x\,\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}\ldots\dd x_{n}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd q\
> \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 2\pi}\,
> \exp\pars{\ic\bracks{q + {\pi \over n}}x}}^{\ds{=\ \delta\pars{q + {\pi \over n}}}}\
> \pars{\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-\ic q\xi}\,\dd\xi}^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}
> \Re\bracks{\pars{\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\ic\pi\xi/n}\,\dd\xi}^{n}}
> =\lim_{n \to \infty}
> \Re\bracks{\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/n}  - 1 \over \ic\pi/n}^{n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}
> \Re\bracks{%
> \expo{-\ic\pi/2}\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/2n}  - \expo{-\ic\pi/2n} \over \ic\pi/n}^{n}}
> =\lim_{n \to \infty}
> \Re\braces{\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\bracks{\sin\pars{\pi/2n} \over \pi/2n}^{n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large 0}
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
> \qquad\qquad\pars{2}
> \end{align}

By replacing $\pars{2}$ in expression $\pars{1}$ we find:
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ldots\int_{0}^{1}
\cos^{2}\pars{{\pi \over 2n}\,\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n}}}
\,\dd x_{1}\,\dd x_{2}\ldots\dd x_{n} = \half}
$$

Comment: Julien Godawatta notes the addendum in [a comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728173/integral-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-int-01-int-01-cos2-big-frac-pi/733464#comment1520530_728173). For some reason, [their answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/728245) was self-deleted.

Comment: @robjohn I just deleted the ADDENDUM. I didn't see the JG comment but now I just checked it is alive. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you delete the addendum. There are many cases where a comment gets promoted to an answer by someone other than the commenter. Good ideas should be in answers, not comments since [comments are ephemeral](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130975).

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you for always answering my integrals:)  I am surprised by your solution though!  I do not see any $\partial_\mu$ ;]

Comment: @Jeff It was not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Using
$$
\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}
$$
we get that
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\cos^2\left(\frac{a\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\,\mathrm{d}x_2\dots\,\mathrm{d}x_n\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\mathrm{Re}\left(\int_0^1\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1e^{\frac{ia\pi}{n}(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)}\,\mathrm{d}x_1\,\mathrm{d}x_2\dots\,\mathrm{d}x_n\right)\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\mathrm{Re}\left(\left[\int_0^1e^{\frac{ia\pi}{n}x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]^n\right)\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\mathrm{Re}\left(\left[\frac{n}{ia\pi}\right]^n\left[e^{\frac{ia\pi}{n}}-1\right]^n\right)\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\mathrm{Re}\left(\left[\frac{2n}{a\pi}\sin\left(\frac{a\pi}{2n}\right)\right]^ne^{\frac{ia\pi}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\left[\frac{2n}{a\pi}\sin\left(\frac{a\pi}{2n}\right)\right]^n\color{#C00000}{\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&\to\frac12+\frac12\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)\\
&=\cos^2\left(\frac{a\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align}
$$
If $a=1$, $\color{#C00000}{\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)}$ is $0$, so the integral is $\frac12$ for all $n$.

Comment: Very nice solution.  Thanks very much!!

Comment: Nice solution! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\big)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n $

$\displaystyle = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(1-x_1+1-x_2+...+1-x_n)\big)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n $

$\displaystyle = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \sin^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\big)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n$

$\displaystyle = \frac12 \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \sin^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\big) + \cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)\big)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n$

$=\dfrac12$

Comment: Hi, I have known about this integral for more than 5 years now, and while I have been able to solve by other means, this solution stumps me. Please if anyone reads this, point me to the right direction.

Comment: @SSBASE The first line is just making the change of variable $x_i \mapsto 1-x_i$ (for each $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$). Then use the fact $\cos \theta = \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$ .. finally add the integrals in line $(1)$ and $(3)$ and divide by $2$ to get the result.

Comment: I see... I was considering that it was due to something $P(X) - P'(X) = 1$ from elementary probability theory. I was also thinking it was due to $cos(x)$ being "orthogonal" to $sin(x)$. Also, how does this  solution deal with the integration interval? (I think this is the cleanest and algebraically simplest solution on this thread, which is why I ask so much).

Comment: @SSBASE Finally we are integrating 1/2 over the unit cube $[0,1]^n$ .. the final result is independent of $n$. There's no point in writing the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ I guess ..

Comment: Apologies, there's a typo. It should be $P(X) + P'(X)=1$. Sorry!

Comment: thank you for responding even 8 years after your original answer!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\displaystyle\frac1n\sum_1^nx_k$ is the mean value of $\bar x$, which, for $n\to\infty$, tends to $\dfrac{a+b}2$ , for $x_k\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Ok, can you elaborate?  This is more of a comment. Thanks

Comment: What are *a* and *b* in our case ? Between which values does each $x_k$ vary ?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the book of Putnam mathematics competition and your question is a little bit different from the original topic.

Since the following relation holds

$$\cos^{2}(π/2n(x_1+\dots+x_n))=\frac14 (e^{iπ/n}(x_1+\dots+x_n)+e^{−iπ/n}(x_1+\dots+x_n))+\frac12$$

it seems that it is not so hard to integrate your function:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1 \cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\big)\,dx_1\, dx_2\dots\,dx_n.
$$

you can use the following formulas:

$$\int{dx_{1}} \int{dx_{2}}\dots\int{f(x_{1})f(x_{2})...f(x_{n})}{dx_{n}} = \frac{1}{n!} (\int{f(\tau)}d\tau)^{'}$$

where, $f(x)=e^{i\pi/n}x$.

It seems that this method will be easy to use.