# Limit of a multiple integral

Tags: integration, limits, probability-distributions

$$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1...\int_0^1 \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1+x_2+...x_n)\right)dx_1 dx_2...dx_n$$

I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Please show some effort. Stated like this it looks like home work you want us to do for you.

Comment: I try, $u=x_1+x_2+x_3+....+x_n$ but .........

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728173/putnam-exam-integral?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to exploit a probabilistic approach. Let $X_1,\ldots X_n$ be independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Our integral computes:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2} M_n\right)\right] $$
where:
$$ M_n = \frac{X_1+\ldots +X_n}{n}. $$
Since $M_n\to \frac{1}{2}$ by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), the given limit equals:
$$ \cos^2\frac{\pi}{4} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}. $$

Comment: I gave the link above. It was an answered question.